# Does the measuring instrument which counts the number of quantum particles exist?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, quantum-error-correction

I have recently been thinking about the quantum deletion error correcting codes, but the primary problem is whether the receiver can detect the loss of quantum particles or not. So my question is that the measuring instrument for counting the number of the particles without affecting the state of the particles exists.

Comment: Depends on the particles. But with sufficient effort, generally yes.

Comment: @NorbertSchuch including the *without affecting the state of the particles* bit? I mean I guess it's in principle possible if there is a defined number of particles, but as soon as you have superpositions of such, you cannot "count the particles" without affecting the state (a trivial example being a coherent state), no?

Comment: @glS Sure you can.  For instance, if you encode a qubit in some internal state of an atom/ion, you can easily shine light on an ion to see if it is still there without affecting the internal state -- you just need to use a transition which is does not involve the levels used to encode the qubit.  Similarly, if you use a photon you can map the state of the photon to the state of an atom e.g. in a way which is selective to the polarization, and then again measure whether the atom is in the qubit subspace or not.  (I'm not saying the latter is easy, but it is clearly possible. ...

Comment: ...   The former is done routinely e.g. in ion traps, or atoms in optical lattices.)

Comment: @NorbertSchuch I mean, sure, but those are indeed examples in which there is a definite number of particles in the system, that is, you have an eigenstate of the number operator. As soon as this is not the case (e.g. coherent states) then measuring the number of particles will collapse the state and thus "affect it". Unless further assumptions are imposed on the structure of the state at least

Comment: @glS I don't see your point.  In any case, the way I understand the question is that you send a qubit encoded on a "carrier particle" (photon -> polarization atom -> internal state), and that carrier particle gets lost.  You want to know when it got lost, without destroying the information encoded on the particle in case it didn't get lost.  This clearly works; I have a hard time imagining a scenario where this is fundamentally impossible.  (Indeed, we know it is fundamentally possible, since there is a POVM measurement for that.  The only question is how tricky it is to implement the latter.)